# Polymer Vaadin grid routing

Tags: polymer, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have a vaadin grid in which I have information in. I would like the grid to instead of open a dialog, to route to a new page just like any other link would do.

I am using app-route, but am not understanding how to get to the next page.

Each row has its own ID which is all that should be passed in the routing. 
I would like each row to have its own link when clicked too. So each id should be localhost:8000/dashboard/{{id}} by calling the same element that builds the page depending on the id passed.

Is there a way to do this out of the vaadin grid?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that with `<vaadin-grid>` would be to observe the [`activeItem`](https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-grid/html-api/elements/Vaadin.GridElement#property-activeItem) property of the grid, and update the URL every time it changes:

**1. observe the `activeItem` grid property**

```
<vaadin-grid items="[[pages]]" aria-label="Navigation Links"
  on-active-item-changed="_onActiveItemChanged">

  <vaadin-grid-column>
    <template class="header">Grid Menu</template>
    <template>[[item.title]]</template>
  </vaadin-grid-column>

</vaadin-grid>
```

**2. define a new path based on the selected grid item**

```
_onActiveItemChanged(e, detail) {
  const activeItem = detail.value;
  if (activeItem) {
    // if a grid item is selected
    this.path = `/dashboard/${activeItem.id}`;
  }
}
```

**3. update the current URL based on the path**

- (for client-side routing) `<app-location path="[[path]]"></app-location>`.
- (for server-side routing) `window.location.pathname = this.path;`.

*This example shows `<vaadin-grid>` 4, but the same principle applies to any other version of the grid as well.*